# Drop group if another column has duplicate values - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following df

```
id  value many other variables
A    5
A    5
A    8  
A    9
B    3
B    4 
B    5
B    9 
C    10
C    11
C    19 
D    6
D    6
D    10
E    0
E    0
E    0
...
```

I want to drop the whole id group if there are duplicate values in the `value` column (except zeros) So the output should be

```
id  value many other variables
B    3
B    4 
B    5
B    9 
C    10
C    11
C    19 
E    0
E    0
E    0
...
```

Comment: Is `id` the index or just a column?

Comment: just a column ---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` to flag the duplicates, then transform `groupby.any` to flag the groups with duplicates. Then to get the rows with 0s, chain this boolean mask with a boolean mask that flags 0s:

```py
out =df[~df.duplicated(['id','value']).groupby(df['id']).transform('any') | df['value'].eq(0)]
```

Output:

```
   id  value many_other_variables
4   B      3                     
5   B      4                     
6   B      5                     
7   B      9                     
8   C     10                     
9   C     11                     
10  C     19                     
14  E      0                     
15  E      0                     
16  E      0
```

Note: `groupby.any` is an aggregation, `transform` transforms that aggregate to match the length of the original DataFrame. The goal is to create a boolean mask to filter `df` with; and boolean masks must have the same length as the original `df`, so we transform the aggregate here.

Comment: question, what does `transform('any')` do here?

Comment: @Olive `groupby.any` is an aggregation, `transform` transforms that aggregate to match the length of the original dataframe. The goal is to create boolean mask to filter `df` with; and boolean masks must have the same length as the original df

Comment: i edited the OP. I would like to also know how to apply this only to non-zero values. I tried adding `notnull()` right after `~df.duplicated(['id','value'].notnull()` but i get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'notnull'`