# Drop group if another column only has duplicate values - pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

My question is quite similar to this one: [Drop group if another column has duplicate values - pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72192833/drop-group-if-another-column-has-duplicate-values-pandas-dataframe)

I have the following dataframe:

```
letter  value   many    other   variables
A          5            
A          5            
A          8            
A          9            
B          3            
B         10            
B         10            
B          4            
B          5            
B          9            
C         10            
C         10            
C         10            
D          6            
D          8            
D         10            
E          5            
E          5            
E          5            
F          4            
F          4
```

And when grouping it by letter I want to remove all the resulting groups that only have value that repeats, thus getting a result like this:

```
letter      value   many    other   variables
A            5          
A            5          
A            8          
A            9          
B            3          
B           10          
B           10          
B            4          
B            5          
B            9          
D            6          
D            8          
D           10
```

I am afraid that if I use the duplicate() function similarly to the question I mentioned at the beggining I would be deleting groups (or the rows in) 'A' and 'B' which should rather stay in their place.

Comment: So, if there is a group with a single row, do you want to delete it? And if there is a group with two repeats (1/1/1/2/2/2), you keep it?

Comment: In this case I know for sure that there are no single rows, it is my bad that I didn't mention that at the beginnig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several possibilities.

Using [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
m = (df.duplicated(subset=['letter', 'value'], keep=False)
       .groupby(df['letter']).transform('all')
    )

out = df[~m]
```

*NB. this won't drop groups with a single row.*

Using [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) and [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html):

```
out = df[df.groupby('letter')['value'].transform('nunique').gt(1)]
```

*NB. this will drop groups with a single row.*

Output:

```
   letter  value  many  other  variables
0       A      5   NaN    NaN        NaN
1       A      5   NaN    NaN        NaN
2       A      8   NaN    NaN        NaN
3       A      9   NaN    NaN        NaN
4       B      3   NaN    NaN        NaN
5       B     10   NaN    NaN        NaN
6       B     10   NaN    NaN        NaN
7       B      4   NaN    NaN        NaN
8       B      5   NaN    NaN        NaN
9       B      9   NaN    NaN        NaN
13      D      6   NaN    NaN        NaN
14      D      8   NaN    NaN        NaN
15      D     10   NaN    NaN        NaN
```

Comment: I tried with the second piece of code and it worked perefectly, thank you very much!!